# Java BufferedWriter performance

Tags: java, performance, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I need to create large test files—near 3 GB. So I try to write for start only string "1"—to check performance and correctness.

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("c:/out.txt");
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream,10000000);
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
  //out.write(Integer.toString(1));
  out.write("1");
  out.newLine();
}
out.close();
```

In future versions I need to write random integers. Now it takes on my computer 3 min 26 s.
Changing size of buffere seems doesn't help.
Is it possible to accelerate process of writing? Thanks.

Comment: Do your files need to consist of string/character data? Here you're going through a text encoding layer that may not be necessary. Please add more detail as to the format of the data you're trying to write into your files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, 3GB is 3072MB - and if you have a writing speed of 25MBps - it should take a bit longer then 2 minutes. Try it on a different computer and compare results - maybe its just you hard drive that isn't fast

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at a raid array in order to speed up your writes.  Writing a lot of data is a slow process.  Also you can look at an SSD or in some in memory methods (ram drive).